# mathematical operations of unknown variables in a list

Tags: python

I want to do something like this in Python:

```
b = 2
c = 3
a = (b*c)
b = 10
print a
30
```

or:

```
b = a = 2
a = 10
print b
10
```

The other thing i want to to is

```
l = [a + b + c]
print l
a + b + c # As a function not as a result so again if i change a the list entry should change
```

This should be on the fly i cannot make a function for every 'a' as there would be quite a long list of different functions. The whole process should happen in a list or in an other storage object (maybe classes but i really have trouble to get warm with them)
I cannot really explain what i try to accomplish its a bit akward piece of code.

Comment: Well, if you don't like the site, nobody is making you use it.

Comment: I dont know yet if i like the site, but it has designflaws and i want to encourage to look into them.

Comment: Remarks, suggestions, complaints etc. about SO itself can be posted on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Your question is not the place to do so: it is only noise.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that kind of thing using lambda functions.

```
In [1]: b = 2

In [2]: c = 3

In [3]: a = lambda: b * c

In [4]: a
Out[4]: <function __main__.<lambda>>

In [5]: a()
Out[5]: 6

In [6]: b = 10

In [7]: a()
Out[7]: 30
```

And, for the list:

```
In [8]: l = lambda: [a(), b, c]

In [9]: l()
Out[9]: [30, 10, 3]

In [10]: b = 1

In [11]: l()
Out[11]: [3, 1, 3]
```

If you wish to not call a and l as functions, you can encapsulate them in a class like this:

```
class A(object):
    @property
    def a(self):
        if callable(self._a):
            return self._a()
        else:
            return self._a
    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value
    @property
    def b(self):
        if callable(self._b):
            return self._b()
        else:
            return self._b
    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b = value
```

Then, you don't have to know when operating whether a and b are lambdas or "normal objects", and you can access them like this:

```
In [13]: x = A()

In [14]: x.a = lambda: x.b * 2

In [15]: x.b = 3

In [16]: x.a
Out[16]: 6

In [17]: x.b = 4

In [18]: x.a
Out[18]: 8
```

Answer (score 1):

[SymPy](http://sympy.org/) will allow you to express and evaluate mathematical operations while deferring the final result until needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish that with `functions`, `lambdas`, or `classes` with `properties`.

```
def c():
  return a * b

c = lambda: a * b

class myclass(object):
  a = 10
  b = 12

  @property
  def c(self):
    return self.a * self.b
```

In the first two examples they'd be invoked as `c()`, in the third you'd need this:

```
instance = myclass()
print instance.c
# change a
instance.a = 12
print instance.c
```